# Ignore certain tags from terraform locals

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can I ignore a certain tag defined in the locals variable?
For example: I would want to ignore the email tag for this dynamodb table resource.

## Local definition

```
locals {
  global_tags = {
    email = "xxx.com"
    owner = "xxx"
  }
  common_tags = {
    Name = "live"
  }
}

 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      read_capacity,
      write_capacity,
      local.global_tags.email
    ]
  }

  tags = merge(local.global_tags,local.common_tags,var.received_nexgen_events_tags)

}
```

Details:

```
Terraform v0.12.0
+ provider.aws v2.30.0
```

I tried this but got an error

Error: Unsupported attribute

on ../../../../tf_module_dynamodb/events.tf line 22, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "events":
  22:       local.global_tags.email

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"local".

2: I also tried like this, got static variable reference is required , what is static variable reference?

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      read_capacity,
      write_capacity,
      local.global_tags["xxx.com"]
    ]
  }


error :
 22:       local.global_tags["xxx.com"]

A static variable reference is required.
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you run that? If so include it in the question. If it doesn't error but doesn't do what you expect then please explain clearly what is happening and what you'd prefer to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a bug in terraform > 0.12 version

The `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` will say that its going to add tag.email, however it will ignore the tag.email when terraform apply command has run.

I tested using terraform state `rm --target=resource-name` and did an import and then did terraform state show resource-name, the tag.email was not imported(was ignored) !

More details: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/167

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      read_capacity,
      write_capacity,
      tags.email  
    ]
  }
```

Comment: There is a typo in the link.